# UIVisuaEffect when pushed into NavigationController loses its blurEffect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.view.bounds)
let frameview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:60,y:120,width:200,height:200))
frameview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
frameview.layer.borderWidth = 2

let tpath = UIBezierPath(rect: frameview.frame)
path.append(tpath)

layer.path = path.cgPath
layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
let blurview = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
let  blur = UIVisualEffectView (effect: UIBlurEffect (style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark))
blur.frame = blurview.bounds
let maskView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
maskView.layer.mask = layer
//blurview.layer.mask = layer
blur.mask = maskView
let imview = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
imview.image = UIImage(named: "embed2")
view.addSubview(imview)

blurview.addSubview(blur)
view.addSubview(blurview)
view.addSubview(frameview)
```

This is what I do in a ViewController. If I normally present it from another view controller I get this:

[image]

But if I push this ViewController into a NavigationController from another ViewController, I get this:

[image]

If I embed this ViewController in a NavigationController, the blur effect is gone.
Why does it happen? I want only the square portion to be visible even if I push the ViewController. What should I do?

Comment: Here is a discussion that *probably* explains what's going on: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50854 ... note: likely won't give you your desired result, but placing your code in `viewDidAppear` gives the blur effect with and without Navigation Controller...

Comment: thank you so much  , it works. But according to the forum, Mr.Rincewood has told to apply mask to the visualeffectview and not the layer , that's y i did this, but what does the navigation controller have to do with this.

Comment: When you push a VC onto a Nav stack, the view is instantiated *before* it is on-screen. As I understand it, that changes the timing of when the Visual Effect is applied, and what image data it has available.

Comment: @DonMag I don't understand what you meant by instantiating a view before it's onscreen. Of course it has to be instantiated before it appears on screen, right? We have a simpler situation than Savitha — we want to blur the entire background. We're not setting a mask to blur only parts of it. The UIVisualEffectView is the root view of a UIViewController, which needs to be presented (not pushed) for the blur to work. We don't know why. Thanks for your help.